# bind-ed function passed as property React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to pass a bound function(param) (has a setState()) as property but I face this error, and I am not actually sure about how to pass this kind of function.

```
Cannot read property 'upadateComment' of undefined
```

this is my class snippet in index.js file, (the class that has the functions)

```
removeComment = (i) => {
    console.log('removing comment: ' + i);
    var arr = this.state.comments;
    arr.splice(i, 1);
    this.setState({comments: arr});
}

upadateComment = (newText , i) => {
    console.log('updating comment: ' + i);
    var arr = this.state.comments;
    arr[i] = newText;
    this.setState({comments: arr});
}


eachComment(text, i) {
    return (
        <Comment                            
        key={i} index={i} updateCommentText={this.upadateComment}//here is the problem
        removeCommentText={this.removeComment}> //and here 
        {text}
        </Comment>
    );
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.state.comments.map(this.eachComment)}
        </div>
    );
}
```

and this is the place for calling them (Comment.js file)

```
edit = () => {
    this.setState({editing: true});
}

remove = () => {
    this.props.removeCommentText(this.props.index);
    console.log('removing');
}

save = () => {
    this.props.updateCommentText(this.refs.newText.value , this.props.index);
    console.log('new Text: ');
    this.setState({editing: false});
}
```

Comment: update the code where you have defined `this.state={};` i.e: constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `eachComment` is a function declaration, it refers to a wrong `this` context. I'd suggest you to change it into an `arrow function`.

```
eachComment = (text, i) => {
    return (
        <Comment                            
        key={i} index={i} updateCommentText={this.upadateComment}
        removeCommentText={this.removeComment}>
        {text}
        </Comment>
    );
}
```